# How can i make query with a predicate that tests null column in Breeze?

Tags: javascript, breeze

How can I make a query with a predicate that tests for null in Breeze?

with a `Predicate.create("region", "==", null)`

I get an 500 http error from server:

> Unable to perform operation: eqon types:

I am using the Asp.Net Breeze Web Api Controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Predicate expressions for null **data property** values **do** work as in your example, but I am guessing that in your query "region" is an instance of the region type.  I will look into this in more detail, but for the time being I am guessing that you also have a "regionID" property or something like it. So maybe try:

```
EntityQuery.from("Territories").where("regionID", "==", null)
```

Comment: Thanks. Looking your answer I found what i had done. I expected a nullable type but it was not in my model.